# Show / Hide Mirrored Loop Cut

Tags: modeling, mirror, loop, mirror-modifier, settings

I've been following a course online where **Loop Cuts** are used. In the demo, the instructor creates a Loop Cut on an object that has a Mirror modifier. As the instructor moves the Loop Cut, the Mirror side also shows the Loop Cut. However, when I try to do the same, I can only see the Loop Cut on my original side until it is placed. Only then can I see the Loop Cut on the Mirror side. Not a deal breaker, but I seen a few comments that there was an option to unhide the Loop Cut on the mirror side. The comments had images, but they are no longer visible in the course I'm taking. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you mean enabling the On Cage option of the Mirror modifier? But it will appear only after you validate with Enter. Same if you display the Wireframe in the Viewport Overlays panel

Comment: Not sure if this a version difference since I don't know which demo you are talking about, which Blender versions you and the instructor use. However, when you say moving the _Loop Cut_ and placing the _Loop Cut_: what exactly do you mean? Because it is normal behavior (at least in recent versions) that before clicking somewhere to place the cut, it only appears on the original side and in the center of the faces to show in which direction you would cut. If you then click on it to place it, you can then slide the cut along the edges, and only then it will be mirrored.